# Game Loop Is Not Destroying

Tags: java, android

**Background**
*I have created a game loop to run the UI, but when I push the back button from the game screen (SingleGameActivity) I get to the level-selector menu called (StartLvlActivity). If I try to reenter the game or push the back button from StartLvlActivity I get a keyDispatchingTimedOut error (ANR).
   When I wrote Log messages, the game activity (SingleGameActivity) was only paused, not stopped when I pushed the back button. And the game loop was never destroyed when I closed the activity.*

```
08-03 09:56:12.130: I/Process(346): Sending signal. PID: 5763 SIG: 3
08-03 09:56:12.130: I/dalvikvm(5763): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-03 09:56:12.333: I/dalvikvm(5763): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-03 09:56:12.341: E/ActivityManager(346): ANR in com.coderogden.pongtennis (com.coderogden.pongtennis/.activities.StartLvlActivity)
08-03 09:56:12.341: E/ActivityManager(346): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
```

**Questions**
1. Why isn't the game loop destroyed when I push the back button from the game menu? I mean, why isn't surfaceDestroyed called when onPaused is called (onStop is never called and I don't know why....).

1. How do I access "/data/anr/traces.txt"
2. How do I handle the errors?

If you can answer any of these questions I would appreciate it very much!

**EDIT**

This is the surface view class from where I start and destroy the thread (or apperently I'm just starting it as it won't shut down when I press "back"-button).

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
    Log.d(TAG, " surface created");
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, " surface destroyed");
}
```

**EDIT 2 (with solution!)**

The bug was fixed by changing this piece of code:

```
boolean retry = true;
while (retry) {
    try {
        thread.join();
        retry = false;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

to this:

```
thread.setRunning(false);
```

**WHY?**
Is it because I need to stop the thread before destroying it?

Comment: Where do you enter the game loop from? Maybe the same thread that runs the game loop is responsible for stopping your app, but it can't because it's trapped in the game loop?

Comment: I am not very familiar with threads as I'm a beginner developer, but I'd be glad if you could teach me how to solve the problem! :)

Comment: Thread.join will wait for the thread to exit. But if it's not going to exit on its own and you don't send any signal to it then it won't exit and the main thread that called thread.join is waiting for the other thread forever.

Comment: Ok! So did I solve the issue the right way? By adding thread.setRunning(false)? It worked fine at least :)

Comment: Depends on what `thread.setRunning(false)` does. If it signals the game loop thread to exit the game loop and finish then that should work.
Try adding `thread.setRunning(false)` before the code you had there before (beginning of `surfaceDestroyed`) and see if that works. Let the main thread print a log message after it has joined the game loop thread (at end of `surfaceDestroyed` after loop). If it prints then you can be sure that the game loop thread has exited and that the main loop has exited the loop (i.e. it's not stuck).

Comment: Right now the game loop thread might finish (e.i. maybe it works as it should). However, I'm not entirely sure about that.

Comment: I did exactly as you said and it worked superb! Thanks a lot! :)